# Nginx multiple roots

Tags: nginx, http, redirect, rewrite, rules

I'd like to divert off requests to a particular sub-directory, to another root location.  How?  My existing block is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;

    location / {
        root   /home/me/Documents/site1;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location /petproject {
        root   /home/me/pet-Project/website;
        index  index.html;
        rewrite ^/petproject(.*)$ /$1;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    } }
```

That is, http://www.domain.com should serve /home/me/Documents/site1/index.html whereas http://www.domain.com/petproject should serve /home/me/pet-Project/website/index.html -- it seems that nginx re-runs all the rules after the replacement, and http://www.domain.com/petproject just serves /home/me/Documents/site1/index.html .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The configuration has the usual problem that generally happens with nginx. That is, using `root` directive inside `location` block.

Try using this configuration instead of your current `location` blocks:

```
root /home/me/Documents/site1;
index index.html;

location /petproject {
    alias /home/me/pet-Project/website;
}
```

This means that the default directory for your website is `/home/me/Documents/site1`, and for `/petproject` URI, the content is served from `/home/me/pet-Project/website` directory.

Comment: what is the usual problem you refer to and why is alias better? the nginx docs give an example using two roots

Comment: The usual problem is that people don't realize how `root` and `location` blocks interact. With `root` directive, nginx appends the path after `location` block to the `root` dir to get the full filesystem path to the file. Therefore, if the path specified in `location` does not exist in the directory specified by `root`, something unexpected to the user happens.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen your explanation helped me understand my mistake. THANKS

Comment: @dcsan The nginx docs examples show roots - one root is for the config file as a whole. The other root directive is for a specific location block - this root overrides the main root directive for that particular location block.

Comment: Yes, the `root` inside `location` overrides the `server` level `root`. However, the unintuitive behavior is that nginx appends the URI to the path defined in `root` directory.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `break` flag added to the rewrite rule, so that processing stops, and as this is inside a location block processing will continue inside that block:

```
rewrite ^/petproject/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

Note I also added `/?` to the matching pattern so that you don't end up with double slashes at the beginning of the url.

Comment: The rewriting isn't needed here at all when `alias` directive is used like it should be used here.